# How to put a condition on Output of a SQL Server Pivot Query

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
SELECT * FROM
(
SELECT Value, health_sys_id,CATEGORY,ffy, LineNumber = R.LINE_NUM_START+'-'+R.LINE_NUM_END
FROM     Query1
INNER JOIN LINE_NUM_RANGE3 R ON LineNumber  BETWEEN R.LINE_NUM_START AND LINE_NUM_END
WHERE  (health_sys_id BETWEEN 'HSI00000008' AND 'HSI00001365') 

) t
PIVOT(
         SUM(Value)
         FOR ffy IN (
         [2018],
         [2019],
         [2020],
         [2021])
) AS pivot_table 
ORDER BY health_sys_id, category
```

I have been using the preceding sql server query to retrieve information from a table.  Mostly all of the health_sys_ids will have 4 values represented by the sum of lines 389-393, line 296, line 466 and line 862.

However, there will be some health_sys_ids will have only 3 lines of data.  I would like to know if the above query can be modified to retrieve only those health_sys_ids that have 4 lines of data.

I tried to use LIMIT unsuccessfully.

Comment: `LIMIT` isn't a keyword in T-SQL, it's `TOP`.

Comment: Please show some sample data and desired results (as tabular text).

Comment: Every time I add a picture of the sample data it is so small that I don't think you will be able to see it.  Wondering is it ok for me to upload to a sharing site and post a link here?  Thank you for responding to my question.

Comment: Neither, add sample data as **tabular text** as I originally suggested. And of course you need to produce a **minimal** example - we don't care about seeing your production data.

Answer (score 0):

I am not certain what you mean by tabular text so I added a picture of the table with my source data.  The outcome I hope to achieve is a table with the following characteristics:
A table with the following column titles `Health_sys_id|category|LineNum|2018|2019|2020|2021|populated` by only those healthg_sys_ids that have 4 values represented by the sum of lines 389-393, line 296, line 466 and line 862.